# Event code: 4005

Tags: machinekey

something weird is happening! is a couple of days that my users are experincing a "logging out" isses, the error message is:

Event code: 4005
Event message: Forms authentication failed for the request. Reason: The ticket supplied was invalid.

Here the data:

1. the website is running on 3 server behind a load balancer
2. yes, machine key is the same all across thw websites, because the configuration is shared and all servers are pointing to the same folder on a NAS, this is the key:

   ```
   <machineKey decryption="AES" decryptionKey=" ... snipped for security reasons ... " 
       validation="SHA1" validationKey=" ... snipped for security reasons ..." />
   ```
3. I created the keys using an console app as suggested here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649308.aspx#paght000007_webfarmdeploymentconsiderations
4. the form auth config is

   ```
   <authentication mode="Forms">
     <forms loginUrl="SignIn.aspx" timeout="525960" />
   </authentication>
   ```
5. the time on the servers is in sync

... Any other suggestions?

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that [this patch](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/09/28/asp-net-security-update-now-available.aspx) is installed on every server in the farm.
(It changes ticket handling; installing it on some of the servers will cause issues)

Comment: I had the same problem and syncing the patches between server fixed it !
Thank you so much for the tip !